# Solana validator stake history

Tags: solana-program, jsonrpc-api, api

Is there any way to get the stake history for a validator on Solana. I am trying to analyze the performance of validators on the network and am able to use the `getInflationReward` method retrospectively to get the rewards a validator received in a certain epoch.

However,in order to understand what was the APR I need to know the stake of the validator in that epoch. is there any method that can retrieve this for a past epoch ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to query the total stake a validator had at a certain epoch.

Your base question, however, is to analyze the performance of validators. If you want to know the performance, you don't actually need to know the total amount staked!

If you have one active stake account on that validator, you can use `getInflationReward` to see what percentage that stake account gained for the epoch. All stake accounts on a validator will have the same relative gain (ie 0.06%), so all you need is one stake account that you know was delegated to the validator, and then go through all epochs to see what percentage the validator was returning to delegators.

Comment: Technically this works. Thanks. As a "hack" i was able to get the stake info from solanacompass website.

Answer (score 0):

The full stake history for all validators is now available at the Solana Stakes website:

https://stakeview.app/stakes